# Best way of saying that your sobriety came back up by a little?

Tags: idiomatic-language

"His level of sobriety rose up a little bit."

Sounds weird, because of level, I think we can remove it.

"His sobriety came back up a little bit."

I can't find any similar phrasing, so I am wondering how a native would say this.

Comment: By "sobriety", do you mean how drunk he was? "Level of sobriety" seems an odd phrasing

Comment: by sobriety i mean the opposite of drunkenness.

Comment: The reason you won't "find any similar phrasing" is because native Anglophones wouldn't normally use that form of words. We'd say [***He sobered up**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22He+sobered+up%22) [a bit].*

Comment: Your question lacks focus and needs more explanation since "sobriety" can mean different things in that context, like if "sobriety" refers to him becoming less intoxicated, then @FumbleFingers suggestion "He sobered up a little bit" is exactly on point, in my opinion, but if "sobriety," for example, instead refers to him living a life free of intoxication, like if that's something he's working towards as a recovering alcoholic or addict and your sentence means he's had a little bit of success in that, you'd keep the word "sobriety" since that's the terminology and maybe use the verb "improve."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal phrasing would be "He sobered up a little" (or "... a bit").  The phrasing "level of sobriety" is awkward.

The phrase verb "to sober up" is odd, because the verb "to sober" is rare in non-phrasal form. As a non-phrasal verb it means "to make or become serious or sad". The phrasal verb "sober up" always refers to becoming less drunk.